# Is it possible to make a memo transparent in Android app using Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

Hi I would like to know is it possible to make a memo transparent? If so, how is it done? I want the user to be able to see the text displaced as well as the background image instead of the just the white background of the memo.

I'm using Embarcadero RAD Studio XE5

Thank you

Comment: Why not use a transparent `TLabel` instead? Or do you need the text to be selectable/editable?

Comment: No. I'm reading data out of a text file. And the only proper way of displaying it is in a memo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the Opacity property to a value lower than 1. I haven't tested this component for Android but buttons, toolbars, images, etc. do work. I tested the TMemo for windows and that too works.

Answer (score 0):

I have XE2, so editing the style may be a little different in XE5. In XE2, you can right-click the TMemo and choose "Edit Custom Style..." from the popup menu.

Find the style for the memo (not the scroll bar), then expand the style down to the background TRectangle.

Set the Fill color and the stroke color for the TRectangle to Null, then click the "Apply and Close" button, and the TMemo will now be "Transparent".

If the steps are different for editing the style in XE5, please let us know. Also, if this isn't what you're looking for, please provide an image demonstrating what you're going for.